# Horizontal alignment of items across environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section*{First}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Second} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item[] Item 1
\item[] Item 2
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

I want the numbering for the first enumerate environment but not for the second; meanwhile, want the items in both to be horizontally aligned (taking into account the numbers in the first environment), i.e., I want them to have the same amount of indentation. Below is the picture that shows what the solution should look like:

[image]

In case of numbers with two more digits, I want the numbers left aligned. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you mean `horizontal` alignment here?

Comment: what should happen, if number in enumerate has two digits? do they be aligned right or left? or you expect that they will always have only one digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

waiting on your response to my comment above, i assume, that enumerate has only one digit numbers followed by dot. in this case it is possible tweak the following (approximation of your image):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section*{First}
    \begin{enumerate}[labelwidth=2.2ex, labelsep=1ex]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
    \end{enumerate}

\section*{Second}
    \begin{enumerate}[labelwidth=2.2ex, labelsep=1ex,
                      label={}, leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelsep+\labelwidth\relax]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**

after your clarification and simplification of requested features, see if the following solution fulfill them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelwidth=3ex, labelsep=1ex, align=left,
                    leftmargin=4em}
\newlist{quoteitem}{enumerate}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[quoteitem]{label={}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{First}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum*[11]
\item[99.] Item 2
    \end{enumerate}

\section*{Second}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{quoteitem}
\item \lipsum*[11]
\item Item 2
    \end{quoteitem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response Zarko. Unfortunately, there may be two digits numbers, in which case I want the same indentation (counting the numbers) for all items. This problem has been bothering me for a while...

Comment: @Daryl, sorry. your request is not clear at all. i believe that your question become to broad ...

Comment: yes, after seeing what samcarter has done, I realized that my problem is more  complicated than I thought. Sorry! So (1) I want the digits to be left aligned (rather than right aligned which is the default as in samcarter's picture); (2) I want the numbers (starting from the first digits) from the first enumerate environment and the "Item"s to be aligned along the same vertical line (a line similar to the one in samcarter 's reply). I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Daryl, see addendum to my answer

Comment: Hi Zarko, this is exactly what I wanted!!! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Daryl, glad to hear this. than you can now accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{First}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Second} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item[\hspace*{\labelwidth}] Item 1
\item[\hspace*{\labelwidth}] Item 2
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter for your help. I  clarified my problem in a reply to Zarko.

Comment: thank you for clarification what op wish and what is possible (simple) to obtain (+1). see addendum to my answer.